# Node.js and MySQL: Too Many Connections Error

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, command-line, mysql-workbench

I'm using a repository from gitHub that collects the reviews from the apps that you add its ID. It uses node.js and mysql.
The number of reviews was incrementing when I had fewer apps. After adding 63 application I -most of the time- get a "Too Many Connections" error when typing "node reviews-to-mysql" command.

Does anyone know what causes this? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a way to fix it" - yes, don't open that much connections :) Most likely good solution for you is to use built in connection pool ( default max number of connections is 10) Also check that you don't just open connection and leave it open after